# Launcher icon is changed but in recent apps still default icon i seen

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-icons

I have changed the launcher icons in File -> New -> Image Asset and the icons are changed.

When I click on recent apps icon in it displays the default icon where as correct icon is shown in the main icon list.

Verified the Android manifest where application tag contain the icon tag and corresponding mipmap.

What's wrong here? I am using xiaomi note 4 mobile. Please help.

Comment: restart the phone, it will  update automatically.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar Thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 29):

**Reboot your phone** and your icon will update in recent apps and notification.

Answer (score 27):

The app icon in the app launcher should be updated, but the shortcuts won't be updated until the next refresh of the home-screen. There isn't much you can do that unfortunately, but the home-screen does refresh itself once in a while, so the new icon will eventually replace the old icon automatically.

Answer (score 2):

From Android Nougat, default launcher icon should be `roundIcon`. See this [Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html)

Maybe you should change your `AndroidManifest` for your `application` tag

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```